# eclipse plugin mirror - hard-coded url prevents installation

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

i have a mirror for eclipse plugins inside a private network that has no connection to the internet. this works all fine so far except for plugins like http://texlipse.sourceforge.net/ or https://borisvl.github.io/Pdf4Eclipse/ .

the problem (probably?) is that there are hard-coded absolute urls inside their `content.jar` files.

for texlipse `content.jar` contains a single file `content.xml` and in there are lines referring to the absolute urls http://texlipse.sourceforge.net/... and 
https://borisvl.github.io/Pdf4Eclipse/... . therefore i can not install any of those features from my mirror. the exlipse updater tries to connect to those urls and fails.

i mirror the plugins with commands like:

```
$ eclipse -application \
             org.eclipse.equinox.p2.metadata.repository.mirrorApplication \
        -nosplash -verbose -source http://texlipse.sourceforge.net/ \
        -destination /texlipse/ -compare

$ eclipse -application \
             org.eclipse.equinox.p2.artifact.repository.mirrorApplication \
        -nosplash -verbose -source http://texlipse.sourceforge.net/ \
        -destination /texlipse/ -compare
```

is there a simple way to get the new urls for the repositories inside my network into the `content.jar` (and the `artifact.jar` and maybe even the `site.xml`)? or do i have to hack that manually?

Answer (score 0):

It's a total hack, but you could modify your [`hosts` file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_(file)) to direct the problematic hostnames to `127.0.0.1`

Comment: thanks for the idea. in that case i'd need to hack the DNS server such that all clients could profit. i still hope the eclipse mirroring tools provide a manner to resolve that.